# Apache SSL problems (Centos 7)

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, ssl

I have deleted `/etc/pki/tls/private` and `/etc/pki/tls/certs`, after that I can't access page. I saw in logs error like

> [suexec:notice] [pid 30215] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled
>   (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)

Is there any method to restart openssl certificates and install new one. I tried with commands `yum reinstal`.... but didn't work.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The message about suexec is not an error and has nothing to do with certificates.

Was there a reason why you deleted /etc/pki/tls/private and /etc/pki/tls/certs?

There is no "restart openssl certificates". If you want certificates, you have to get them from somewhere. Where did you get your last ones?

The apache log files should contain the reason why apache fails to start.